# Why two requests generated while creating new soapui project

Tags: request, soapui

When we create a new soapui project why 2 requests generated instead of 1. For eg in the attached snapshot one is "StockQuoteSoap" and other is "StockQuoteSoap12". while xml request is same under both of these.

[image]

So what is the purpose of two same requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is for SOAP version 1.1, the other is for SOAP version 1.2. This is generated via the WSDL from your server.